# How to get data from Cloud Firestore and Translate it into Local Usable Data (Cordova/Angular)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cordova, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Cloud Firestore as a Database for my Ionic/Cordova App.

My problem is trying to "get" the stored data from Firestore database and use them in my "calculation functions".

My Database structure in Firestore is as follows:

```
UniqueID (collection)
                       >
                         1000  (document)
                                           >
                                              Year (field)
                                              Info (field)
                         1020  (document)
                                           >
                                              Year (field)
                                              Info (field)
                         8394  (document)                                               
                                              Year (field)
                                              Info (field)
                         4543  (document)
                                           >
                                              Year (field)
                                              Info (field)
```

My current code is able to retrieve/get data from Firestore however I can't utilize this data yet as i couldn't find a way to do that.

**Get data function:**

```
firebase.firestore().collection(`${user.uid}`).get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });
```

This doc.id is showing the document name and doc.data() is showing the Fields value inside that document.

This function retrieve all documents inside the collection. *(as intended)*
I tried using Observable with Interface but couldn't get it to work.

**Is there a way to dynamically save retrieve data to an object of some kind and then use it in other functions?**

Thank you

Comment: Not clear what specific problem is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to map the data, right?

```
function list(user) {
  return firebase.firestore()
    .collection(user.uid)
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      const list = [];

      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const data = doc.data()
        data.id = doc.id;
        list.push(data);
      });

      return list;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });
}

list({ uid: 'some-valid-uid' }).then((list) => {
  console.log(list);
});
```